# React Native Dropdown Picker don't click option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I am new in react native.

My question is pretty simple:  I use package react-native-dropdown picker, but when I open the dropdown I can't click the option, it's click the Avatar under the option. Example I want to click Housing and it's open Avatar modal from Yvonee, not filter the category.
Any suggestion how to solve? Here is my code:

```
<View style={[styles.filterCompany, Platform.OS !== 'android' ? { zIndex: 1 } : null]}>
                    <DropDownPicker
                        items={colleguesList}
                        open={showDropDown}
                        setOpen={() => setShowDropDown(!showDropDown)}
                        value={category}
                        setValue={value => setCategory(value)}
                        dropDownContainerStyle={{
                            width: 170,
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: 10,
                            borderColor: Colors.SBLighBlue,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.SBLighBlue
                        }}
                        textStyle={{
                            fontFamily: customFonts.medium,
                            color: Colors.SBWhite,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}
                        labelStyle={{
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: Colors.SBWhite
                        }}
                        arrowIconStyle={{
                            tintColor: Colors.SBWhite
                        }}
                        tickIconStyle={{
                            tintColor: Colors.SBWhite
                        }}
                        listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
                        style={{
                            width: 170,
                            height: 40,
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            marginTop: 10,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.SBLighBlue,
                            borderColor: Colors.SBLighBlue,
                            zIndex: 1
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                    <View style={styles.listAvatar}>
```

Here is image of problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

##### The Problem

You are trying to update the `showDropDown` variable with the `setShowDropDown` in the wrong way. since the `setState` method is an asynchronous action, you are faced with this issue.

##### The Solution

use `prevState` within an **callback** in the `setState` method to update the `showDropDown` properly:

```
<DropDownPicker
  setOpen={() => setShowDropDown((prevState) => !prevState)}
  // ...
/>
```